# get a value from firebase document collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, document

I don't know how to convert these type of data or if my code will works well by this way.

this my function

[image]

I'm trying to get a value from the doc by it's id
this doc has a fields one of them is..

image : 'url'

I want to get 'url' field as String.

another problem:

is this code right?
[image]

and how I can use it in a condition?

================================================================

Edit:

[image]

image 2

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste images but code, so people can copy it.

Comment: @Mises Images do not qualify as an MCVE. Remember to flag the question next time (under "community specific reasons"). You're welcome to comment in addition to flagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chnage `snapshot['image']`

to `snapshot.get("image")`

or use this way :

```
getPhotoUrl(String documentId)async{
await yourCollection
.doc(documentId)
.get()
.then((doc) async {
if (doc.exists) {
return doc.get("image");
        }
  });
}
```

Comment: **Mod note**: Stack Overflow is an English site. This extends to comments. I've purged a huge number of non-English comments; keep further dialog in English